# Which version of Ubuntu support HP ProLiant ML350e Gen8 Server?

Tags: hp, raid5

Which version of Ubuntu support   HP ProLiant ML350e Gen8 Server ??

will in future versions of ubuntu , the raid 5 will be supported ?

Comment: Many people use RAID-5 on Ubuntu Server. What is it that you need exactly? Are you asking about whether or not there is a driver for a specific hardware RAID controller?

Comment: System is certified with Dynamic Smart Array disabled : this is mentioned in the HP certification : hense the question that if the raid 5 will work ( even without certfication)

Answer (score 0):

at least 12.04 is certified for that server. 
raid 5 is supported, why should it not be supported anymore in the future?
[HP ProLiant ML350e Gen8](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201206-11148/)

Comment: System is certified with Dynamic Smart Array disabled